# How to show in terminal all processes which use ports with one command?

Tags: linux, process

How to show in terminal all processes which use ports with one command? ( show ports as well)
I guess it should be something like `lsof...` but need to specify a port, but I need all ports used altogether with processes

Comment: My `lsof` man page includes several examples of how to do this. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sudo netstat -tup
```

It will display all ports and processes that opened them.